# How to send imageview with intent?

Tags: android

the below is the image adapter. I assigned `setOnClickListener` when I click it , I start a new intent to a new activity, but I want to send this image in this adapter to another activity and set it an image view. my problem is I didnt know how to transfer `viewholder.image` to bitmap and send it through intent. how to that

```
    View row = convertView;
  final  ViewHolder holder;

    if (row == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mcontext);
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
    }
    Listitem item = getItem(position);
    System.out.println("item.getUrl() ");
    System.out.println(item.getUrl());

    holder.imageTitle.setText(item.getId());
    Picasso.
            with(mcontext).
            load(item.getUrl())
            .placeholder(R.drawable.logo)
            .fit()
            .into(holder.imageView);

    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.d("OnImageButton", "Clicked");
            Intent intnt  =new Intent(mcontext, SingleViewActivity.class);
            Bitmap imageID=holder.imageView; // error here
            intnt.putExtra("ImageId", imageID);
            mcontext.startActivity(intnt)  ; 

            Toast.makeText(mcontext, "intent",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


    return row;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView imageTitle;
    ImageView imageView;
}
```

Comment: See my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32131605/how-to-move-image-captured-with-the-phone-camera-from-one-activity-to-an-image-v/32132186#32132186 to see if it can help you or not

Comment: @bnk I did solve this but thanks for recomandation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't sent the `Bitmap`. Send the url and use Picasso to retrieve it. The library keeps the Bitmap cached on the disk, so it will not download it again, and loading it from the disk cache will not take long

Comment: hello man ,.. why its better reading from the cache than sending the image to imageview, what  is the difference? and is it enough in `singleviewactivity` to run onlypicasso ?

Comment: well... Passing the `String` will require less memory than passing the whole bitmap

Comment: do you still have questions on this topic?